# How do i send mail from server using php?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to use phpmailer for sending mails. Now it was working fine with my localhost, but as soon as I uploaded it on my website, it never worked? Can anyone tell me how to make it work, or where I could find the solution? I tried googling it, but it did not help much.

Code with localhost -

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body=$_POST["purpose"]." mailed to you by - ".$_POST["name"]." ( ".$_POST["number"].",".$_POST["email"].")";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "gmail_username";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "gmail_password";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom($_POST["email"], 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("harshitladdha93@gmail.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = $_POST["subject"];

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "hladdha.bhl2009@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  header( 'Location: http://www.facebook.html' ) ;
} else {
  header( 'Location:http://www.google.com' ) ;
}

?>
```

for my server I did the following changes -

```
<?php
$mail->Host       = "mail.exoticalstudio.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "contact@exoticalstudio.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "password_for_webmail";            // GMAIL password

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  header( 'Location: http://www.facebook.html' ) ;
} else {
  header( 'Location:http://www.google.com' ) ;
}

?>
```

I tried using error info without using a form and directly running the script where i get the error of authorization failure. How do i solve this?

```
    SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [50.22.12.14] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 CHUNKING 
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=787 534 5.7.14 54 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Flushed oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp 
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp 
The following From address failed: harshitladdha93@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp
SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp

The following From address failed: harshitladdha93@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp
SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp

SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp

The following From address failed: harshitladdha93@gmail.com : MAIL not accepted from server,530,5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp
SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp

SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 oo13sm84286802oeb.0 - gsmtp
```

It says suspicious login activity found, how do i make it a trusted activity please help.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get errors? Crashes? Mail simply doesn't get sent? (2) Did you check error logs?

Comment: `$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com;` seems you are missing closing quotes here.

Comment: I did put those quotes there, missed them here while commenting, and what i mean by does not work - i do not get redirected to facebook or google so i dont know if mail was sent or not. I checked error logs, php errors are not shown but in my email i did not get any mail or there is no mail in my sent mail

Comment: have you checked that mail method enable in the server?

Answer (score 0):

We send emails with phpmailer through gmail like this:

```
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

I think you need at least the `ssl://` part. But probably the whole string should be this.
(Or if only the comments are misleading in your second snippet, then probably the mailer settings are wrong...)

Otherwise `$mail->ErrorInfo` contains the error if `$mail->send()` returns with `false`.

And generally it is a good practice to add an `exit()` after the `header('Location:...');` calls. (You can ensure that procession will be terminated this way.)

Comment: I tried this too, but i did not make it work, and i used header just to test the working of send function.

Comment: Is there anything in Errorinfo?

Comment: I edited the question to show the errors, please note that the username and password are correct.

Comment: Okay thanks i got it though, i had to add the website to the trusted applications list...

Answer (score 0):

You have to check which version of php support by your server and smtp and ssl port are enable or not on your server. If server support php old version like 5.2 something then you have to use old version of phpmailer. For this you can create a php file like phpinfo.php and enter the following code inside it-

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```